# Retrive all image urls from a css

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have been searching the web for a couple of days and I have not been able to find what I need.

What I want is to match all background image urls within a CSS file using javascript regular expressions.

ex:

```
background:url('images/sprite-global.png'); // should return 'images/sprite-global.png'
background-image: url('images/sprite-global.png'); should also return 'images/sprite-global.png'
background:url( 'images/sprite-global.png' );// should return 'images/sprite-global.png' even if we have spaces.
background:url('http://mysite.com/css/images/sprite-global.png'); // should return 'http://mysite.com/css/images/sprite-global.png'
```

However, it should not return anything for:

```
{
display:none;
}
```

It looks easy but so far , the best result I have is: url('images/sprite-global.png') using:

```
/url\(([^\)]+\)/i
```

Does anyone know which expression I could use?

Thanks

Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2V5Gg/2/

```
/url\((.*?)\)/
```

I'm not exactly sure what your requirements are since `url` can also use double quotes or no quotes or if you would be worried about the paths containing the string "url" or parentheses, but this at least works with your examples.  Rather than try to get an exact regex to handle trimming, it's easier to just use `$.trim`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that expression returns 'url(<url>)' . What I need is just the <url>.

Comment: @HugoChan it shouldn't .. it depends on how you retrieve the match.  Did you look at my jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry mate, the jsfiddle looks empty

Comment: Your expression is working. However the issue I have is to retrieve all the image urls from a css file. So far the best I manage to get was the first occurrence. How would you get all urls within a string?

Comment: @HugoChan you can either split the lines and iterate over each one or use the `g` modifier in the regex to fill an array with matches